# What do these different highlighted colors mean in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

Can anyone tell me what the difference of color - highlighted while dragging by mouse - really means, and how can the status be defined by javascript?

Here's what I mean:

[image: Dragging Status #1]

[image: Dragging Status #2]

as you can see, their highlighted colors are different.

It's not customized, just the default.

Comment: is this eye test?

Comment: first of all try yourself and after that ask where is your code

Comment: Why does this matter?

Comment: If you want to know why they chosed blue not red is because chrome dev thought it will represent that tag element better

Comment: It’s grey if the page containing the selection isn’t in focus. Try highlighting a word on this page, then focusing the browser’s navigation bar.

Comment: @Soviut why does not matter?

Comment: @O.Rares ok, next

Comment: @Ryan yeah, um.. so you mean that it shows the difference between in focus and not in focus, ryt?

Comment: @Junsfavorite: yes.

Comment: @Bhargav I didn't even write code, juz asking.

Comment: @Ryan thx Ryan. I asked this because my web always shows grey at the first time I join. then it shows blue after focusing to anything else except my web page.

Comment: How is this tagged JavaScript?

Comment: This has nothing to do with javascript. It should not be tagged (or titled) as such.

Comment: dumbos are all here, dun even noe 'bout the issue

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Javascript; This is normal browser behaviour. The difference is between the highlight colour when focused versus unfocused on a page. It's blue when you're focused and gray when you're unfocused.

This is a visual cue so that when you have multiple browser windows open, with a selection in each, you can tell which is the focused one that will be affected if you were to, say, copy that text.